# Programacion Imperativa multihilos y sockets

Tags: python, python-3.x

Conozco los hilos a nivel teórico, se que existen dos módulos para hacer uso de ellos, uno es de bajo nivel y el otro de alto nivel, el primero es el threading y el segundo es el thread, esto lo he visto en una wiki, después de eso se que existen muchísimos métodos pero no se cual usar para mi propósito osea una chat local que puede atender multiples clientes, lo que tengo ahora es un servidor que puede atender solo un cliente, si me conecto con otro cliente se cierra la conexión, el código es el siguiente
informo que no domino muy bien la programacion orientada a objetos por lo tanto agradesco que la solucion este de acuerdo a este estilo

```
#servidor
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 6666

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print ("Socket Created")
sock.bind((host, port))
print ("socket bind complete")
sock.listen(1)
print ("socket now listening")

while 1:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        try:

             print('conexion con {}.'.format(addr))

             conn.send("server: Hello client".encode('UTF-8'))

             while True:

                 datos = conn.recv(4096)
                 if datos:
                     print('recibido: {}'.format(datos.decode('utf-8')))

                 else:
                     print("prueba")
                     break

        finally:
            conn.close()



#cliente
import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 6666

sock = socket.socket()

sock.connect((host, port))

datos = sock.recv(4096)
print (datos.decode('utf-8'))

while True:

  message = input("envia un mensaje")
  sock.send(message.encode('utf-8'))

  if message == "quit":
    break
    print("bye")
    sock.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Para crear un servidor multihebra, tienes que pasar conexiones entrantes a hebras. Así el servidor puede seguir aceptando nuevos conexiones mientras el cliente se comunica en la nueva hebra. En [esta pregunta en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828264/how-to-make-a-simple-multithreaded-socket-server-in-python-that-remembers-client) se encuentra código para un servidor simple en la respuesta de [nettux443](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2814626/nettux443).

Este ejemplo es simplificado porque no es completamente asincronico, cada conexión todavía funciona en un dialogo secuencial. Lo principal es de mover el método que bloquéa (`.recv(size)`) en una hebra propia.

```
import socket
import threading

class ThreadedServer(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))

    def listen(self):
        self.sock.listen(5)
        while True:
            client, address = self.sock.accept()
            client.settimeout(60)
            threading.Thread(target = self.listenToClient,args = (client,address)).start()

    def listenToClient(self, client, address):
        size = 1024
        while True:
            try:
                data = client.recv(size)
                if data:
                    # servidor espejo: se devuelve la misma información que 
                    # el cliente envió 
                    response = data
                    client.send(response)
                else:
                    raise error('Cliente desconectado')
            except:
                client.close()
                return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port_num = input("Puerto? ")
    ThreadedServer('',port_num).listen()
```

El método `listen` crea el socket que escucha a conexiones entrantes. Luego de aceptar una conexión, llama a `listenToClient` en una nueva hebra para inmediatamente poder seguir recibir más conexiones, mientras tanto la nuebva hebra maneja la conexión al cliente.

Dentro de la hebra de una conexión particular, en este ejemplo se espera a datos entrantes, respondiendo con una copia exacta de los datos recibidos (servidor espejo) y despues volviendo de esperar más datos. Este procedimiento se repite hasta que sale el `except` por interrupción de conexión (por ejemplo porque el cliente cerró la conexión).

Para un chat se tuviera que pasar los datos entrantes a la ventana de mensajes y se tiene que implementar un acceso a la conexión para enviar mensajes fuera de la hebra que escucha.

Comment: disculpa pero no es posible hacerlo tambien con el paradigma imperativo, no tengo mucha familiaridad con la opp

Comment: no entendi porque defines dos funciones listen y porque al final le pones una condicional

Comment: El método `listen` es el que se encarga desde el hilo principal de estar esperando  constantemente la llegada de clientes nuevos. Cuando le llega uno se crea un nuevo hilo solo para ese clliente que usa `listenToClient` para procesar los datos que envie ese cliente. La idea es la misma que en tu código pero cada cliente es escuchado en un hilo aparte.

Comment: disculpa mi ignorancion pero es posible hacerlo sin clases ni objetos al estilo imperativo, porque pasas el parametro self a todas las funciones, porque a la primera funcion y a la ultima condicional le pasas guines bajos